# Android full screen activity error

Tags: android, fullscreen

I am trying to create a full screen activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
```

I get the following error:

```
requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

Comment: Are you using ActionBarSherlock or AppCompat ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `requestWindowFeature` **before** `super.onCreate`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
```